# Amazon Elastic Container Service web application with changing data such as file uploads

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I am looking to launch a web application which will cater to approximately 1 million users and therefore I will need to scale to multiple web and database servers. After testing lots of different solutions I have decided to use the Amazon Elastic Container Service (ECS).

The system uses docker images to launch instances but my web application allows users to upload files etc. so at the moment, the files would be uploaded to different docker containers and be lost when the instance is terminated.

What is the best practice to handle docker images running asynchronously with changing contents? The only solution I have thought of is to launch a separate EC2 instance with permanent storage which will store all file uploads.

Comment: I would suggest using S3 or investigate one of the AWS DB services depending on the size/type of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, you should treat those Docker containers as stateless processing. Consider anything stored locally on the containers host machine (EC2) as temporary storage.

If you need to store files, S3 is the way to go. It will likely be the cheapest, easiest to setup and most scalable solution.

If you need to store extra data (ie metadata) with the files, store the file in S3 and the metadata in DynamoDB. Typically what I've done in the past is generate a UUID for the filename and store that in S3 and then use the UUID as the partition key in DynamoDB.

Super easy to setup and will scale well beyond 1 million users.